# Volley GET Method: Not right response to me

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I need your Idea to improving my PHP Code to Use in Android Application. 
This is My PHP Code:

```
require_once 'include\config.php';
// connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

//GETS
if(isset ($_GET['ID']) && isset($_GET['Rating'])){
$ID = $_GET['ID'];  
$MyRate = $_GET['Rating'];  }
else{return;}


//CountVote
$sql1="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `Counter`= `Counter`+1 WHERE `ID`=$ID";
$sql2= "SELECT `Counter` FROM `civilarticle` WHERE `ID`=$ID";
if($con->query($sql1) === TRUE ){
    //echo "Item updated successfully"."<br>";
} else{
    echo "Error : " . $con->error ;
}
if ($result = $con->query($sql2)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $COUNTVote=$row["Counter"];
    //echo "<br>".$row["Counter"]."<br>"."*****"."<br>";
}}


//PASTVote
if(`Counter`<1){
$sql3="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `PastRate`= (`PastRate`+$MyRate)/2 WHERE `ID`=$ID";}
else{$sql3="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `PastRate`= 0 WHERE `ID`=$ID";}
$sql4= "SELECT `PastRate` FROM `civilarticle` WHERE `ID`=$ID";
if($con->query($sql3) === TRUE ){
    //echo "Item updated successfully"."<br>";
} else{
    echo "Error : " . $con->error ;
}
if ($result = $con->query($sql4)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $PASTVote=$row["PastRate"];
    //echo "<br>".$row["PastRate"]."<br>"."*****"."<br>";
}}  

//YOURVote
$sql5 = "UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `YourRate`='$MyRate' WHERE `ID`=$ID";
$sql6="SELECT `YourRate` FROM `civilarticle` WHERE `ID`=$ID";
if($con->query($sql5) === TRUE){
    //echo "Item updated successfully"."<br>";
} else{
    echo "Error : " . $con->error ;
}
if ($result = $con->query($sql6)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $YOURVote=$row["YourRate"];
    //echo "<br>".$YOURVote['YourRate']."<br>"."*****"."<br>";
}}  

//AVVote
if(`Counter`<1 ){
$sql7="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET `Rating`=($MyRate + (`Counter`-1)*`PastRate`)/`Counter`  WHERE ID=$ID";}
else{$sql7="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `Rating`= $MyRate WHERE `ID`=$ID";}
$sql8= "SELECT `Rating` FROM `civilarticle` WHERE `ID`=$ID";

if($con->query($sql7) === TRUE){
    //echo "Item inserted successfully"."<br>";
} else{
    echo "Error : " . $con->error ;
} 
if ($result = $con->query($sql8)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $AVVote=$row["Rating"];
    //echo "<br>".$row["Rating"]."<br>"."*****"."<br>";
}}  

$arr=array("OldRate"=>$PASTVote,"YourRate"=>$YOURVote,"TotalRate"=>$AVVote,"CountVote"=>$COUNTVote);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The output of this is like this:

[image]

And My SQLdatabase Working rigth:

[image]

But when I Run My Application Run with this Code, I Get Wrong Output:

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

//
    private static final String TAG =DetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    TextView txtMain,txtTiltle;
    ImageView imgView;
//
    String title;

    ///
    int ID=2; //put extra give me this value
    public float Rate;
    Button btn_submit,btn_detail;
    RatingBar ratingbar;

//get ?"+"ID="+ID+"&"+"Rating="+Rate
    String url= "http://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/rating.php?"+"ID="+ID+"&"+"Rating="+Rate;
TextView pastrate,yourrate,totalrate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    txtTiltle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMain);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);


    ///
    btn_detail= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    pastrate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    yourrate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
    totalrate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t3);
    ////

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras!=null){
        if(extras.containsKey("Title")){
            title = extras.getString("Title");
            txtTiltle.setText(title);
        }
    }

    ///my code for rating
    btn_submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Rate = ratingbar.getRating();
           // Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,""+ratingbar.getRating(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(Rate!=-1){
                btn_submit.setEnabled(false);


            }


        }

    });



    btn_detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            CustomRequest CustomRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {
                                pastrate.setText(response.getString("OldRate"));
                                yourrate.setText(response.getString("YourRate"));
                                totalrate.setText( response.getString("TotalRate"));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                             Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,response+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "Error occurred ", volleyError);
                   //Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    volleyError.printStackTrace();
                }
            }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("ID", );
                        params.put("Rating",);
                        return params;
                    }
            };
            Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, valueOf(Rate),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(CustomRequest);
        }
    });


}

}
```

The Output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuCl1.jpg)

I Know That My Button Dont Work Becaus UnDifine, But Whats About Get Method for Seen Right votes from SQL Database is Wrong!?

---

I updated my screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you want to know exactly ?

Comment: Does my code work properly?
What's your problem
Why does not Android show the correct value?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to accomplish with the app. Your code is correct as I see. But in the screenshots I'm confused about which is btn_submit and which is btn_detail. Please change the button text accordingly. Also change the textview's text with OldRate , YourRate and TotalRate accordingly so that it's easier to debug your problem.

Comment: I made This again for you, please see my edited Q...

Comment: Why My Counter Vote Works Correct But my Vote not Set Correct And the sended value always is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using CustomRequest CustomRequest, I think you might be getting an error here.

Apart from that there is no need of using a CustomRequest here. You can use JsonObjectRequest here. Just replace CustomRequest with JsonObjectRequest of volley. Let's take it further from there !!

Comment: Please check My Answer, Thank You

Comment: You must use single quotes to enclose PastRate. Change : (`PastRate`+$MyRate)/2  with ('PastRate'+$MyRate)/2

Comment: Are you sure?  But when I changed this my output in browser to be:
`Error : Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'PastRate'{"OldRate":"0.00196074","YourRate":"3","TotalRate":"0.0495487","CountVote":"63"} `
before changing was correct!!!